# convert string to german date java

Tags: java, date-formatting

my problem is the following. I would like to have the german date for the string "11.11.2012".

I tried this piece of code:

```
String date = "11.11.2012";
SimpleDateFormat sdtF = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.mm.yyyy",Locale.GERMANY);
Date dareFormatiert = sdtF.parse(date);
System.out.println(dareFormatiert);
```

But it gives me the wrong format. "Wed Jan 11 00:11:00 CET 2012", instead of "11.11.2012".

Thank you, any help is appreciated.

Comment: mm = minutes. MM = months. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: hi, thank you!

i changed it to 

    SimpleDateFormat sdtF = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy",Locale.GERMANY);

but i still have the same output: Sun Nov 11 00:00:00 CET 2012

Comment: @RudyMcDuty what do you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
but i still have the same output: Sun Nov 11 00:00:00 CET 2012
```

Try to understand the thing when you use

[SimpleDateDFormat#parse()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String,%20java.text.ParsePosition)) - It parses text from a string to produce a Date.
and Date object in java always contains date along the time.

[Javadoc says Date()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) - Allocates a Date object and initializes it so that it represents the time at which it was allocated, measured to the nearest millisecond.

and FYI `Sun Nov 11 00:00:00 CET 2012  is equal to 11.11.2012`

**Edit**: try this

```
public static Date convertUtilDateToSqlDate(java.util.Date date){
        if(date != null && !(date.equals(""))) {
            java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());
            return sqlDate;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

pass the util date you got above and this method shall return the sql format date then store the sqlformat date in mysql column-field of type Date

Comment: I know but I need the string only in this form to store it in a MySQL-database. with "Sun Nov 11 00:00:00 CET 2012" I'm not able to order the data.

Comment: you are providing a string converting to date and again want string in the same format it doesnot makes sense right? what exactly is your requirement?

Comment: my requirement ist to save the string in MySQL and order the data. it doesnt work when i save a string or a date-object.I also used the MySQL dataypes DATE and DATETIME to store

Answer (score 9):

You have to use `M` in you pattern, because `M` is the month and `m` is the minute!

```
String date = "11.11.2012";
SimpleDateFormat sdtF = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy",Locale.GERMANY);
                                                ^^^^
Date dareFormatiert = sdtF.parse(date);
System.out.println(dareFormatiert);
```

For more information see the [documentation of SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)